# How do you write test of Invocable Class?

Tags: apex, invocable-method

I am calling this class from Flow to loop through picklist values inside the Position Picklist field.
I am stuck at 53% coverage for my test class. The section between two == in the class is not getting covered. I am not sure how to write a test class for those lines. Thank you.

Class

```
public class candidateInvocableClass {
    
    @InvocableMethod(label='get Candidate Position Picklist Values' description='Loop through picklistvalues and check if the value is presents' category='candidates__c ')
    public static List<String > getPicklistValues(List<Id> ids) {
        List<String>positionPleValues = new List<String>();
        List<candidates__c> candi = [SELECT webPosition__c,Referral_Source__c from candidates__c WHERE id in :ids ];
        DescribeFieldResult describe = candidates__c.positionPicklist__c.getDescribe(); 
        List<PicklistEntry> availableValues = describe.getPicklistValues();  
       
       //below section is not getting coverage. Need help here. 
      ==============================================
        For(candidates__c record: candi){
            For (PicklistEntry ple: availableValues){
                If(ple.getValue() == record.webPosition__c && record.Referral_Source__c == 'Website')
                {
                
                    positionPleValues.add('yes');
                    break;
                }
                
                else 
                { 
                    positionPleValues.add('no');
                    break;
     ==============================================
                }           
            }  
        } 
        return positionPleValues;
    }
    
}
```

Test Class

```
@isTest
public class candidateInvocableClassTest {
    
    @isTest static void doTest() {
    
       
        Candidates__c record = new Candidates__c( 
                                                                      Referral_Source__c = 'Website',          
                                                                      webPosition__c = 'Associate',
                                                                      positionPicklist__c = 'Associate');
     
        Test.startTest();

        Insert record;
         
        
        Test.stopTest();
        
        record = [Select Referral_Source__c, webPosition__c, positionPicklist__c from Candidates__c WHERE ID=:record.Id];
        system.assertEquals('Associate', record.webPosition__c);
        system.assertEquals('Associate', record.positionPicklist__c);
        system.assertEquals('Website', record.Referral_Source__c);
           
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many situations, there's nothing special about testing thing X vs testing thing Y.

In pretty much every scenario, you follow the same general pattern

1. Set up your test environment. Create the data that the code you're testing needs to have to cause your chosen code path to execute.
2. Call the method you want to test
3. Gather results, and make assertions to verify that the code being tested behaved as expected

An invocable method can be called just like any other method, and for unit tests it's generally better to call your target method as directly as you can. So instead of relying on Salesforce's mechanism to call your method (dml on a record eventually causes flows/process builder to run, which in turn call your invocable method), just call it yourself.

You'll still need to insert your test record, but your test structure would change to something like

```
insert testRecord;

Test.startTest();
candidateInvocableClass.getPicklistValues(new List<Id>{testRecord.Id});
Test.stopTest();
```

This is a *unit* test, and the unit that you're testing is `getPicklistValues()`. You shouldn't generally test things that you don't have control over. How invocable methods get called as part of a flow or a process builder is Salesforce's responsibility. We have no control over how that works, and should trust that Salesforce (and their testing processes) gets it right.

Your assertions would also change here. Since you're testing the behavior of `getPicklistValues()` directly, your assertion(s) should be checking which value(s) were returned by that method (a sequence of 'yes' and 'no').

Comment: Thanks, Derek. How do you check for the values returned by getPicklistValues()?

Comment: @calo That's something you need to define yourself. You're testing your own `getPicklistValues()` method here, not the one from your `DescribeFieldResult`. You should craft your test data so that you have a known result. You then call the method you're testing, assign the return value to a list, and then assert that the two lists are equal. Perhaps `System.assertEquals(list1, list2)` would be sufficient, or perhaps you might need to iterate through each index of both lists to see that every element is equal `for(Integer i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++){ system.assertEquals(list1[i], list2[i]);}`